# Tikz grid on direct process compile vs compiling twice vs compiling in IDE

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling

I've somewhat fixed my problem, but looking into insight as to why things are behaving the way they are. Question relates to compiling proceses, so I don't think a MWE is really required, but have provided one at the end just in case. This post ended up being quite long, so sorry in advance for the story but it feels relevant to how I arrived at my current dilemma.

Context: I'm trying to design an "exam generator" through python which takes a library of questions, a selection on the type of questions to include and how long the exam should be, and then create the exam and solutions by selecting questions that match the criteria and importing them to a xelatex document. Then, it compiles the document for the user so they have the pdf ready to go.

Most of the document is created without issues - however, I've created a series of grids for many questions using Tikz. When running every question through overleaf and TeXstudio, the grids look exactly what I want them to look like. However, when running the python program, they seem to be being created somewhere in the header instead.

The process I ran that achieved this is:

```
xelatex Exam_Qs.tex
```

To try and fix this, I copied the process TeXstudio was using, and so started running this instead:

```
xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Exam_Qs".tex
```

This causes the grids to display in the correct page, but now sometimes they are shifted. Experimenting suggests that one will always display correctly, but it isn't consistent which one it is. I typically only use IDEs, so I'm not comfortable with running the process differently. My understanding is that the nonstopmode tells the TeX engine to run past errors as much as it can, and that the synctex option allows the IDE to correlate the source and PDF position. I'm sure the synctex option isn't doing much for my final intended purpose, but when things weren't working it made sense to copy the TeXstudio process entirely.

The thing that really confuses me is that running the process directly vs inside TeXstudio should produce, at least in my mind, the same document. However, compiling the same .tex document in TeXstudio produces the grid how I expect it to look EVERY time, whereas calling the process in python seems to make it look wrong EVERY time, and always in different ways.

After typing all of this up and re-creating my issues so I could describe them completely, I ended up getting python to just run the process twice and - lo and behold - the grids are showing up exactly how I expect them to. So, finally, my questions:

1. Why does running the process twice cause the document to dispaly properly/why is running the process once causing the document to not display properly.
2. Can I modify the process I'm calling so that I don't have to call it twice?

Some MWEs of the grids I'm making:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, headheight=1.25cm, headsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} % for creating pictures using tikzpicture

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \label{grid}
    % Define the size of the grid squares
    \def\minorsize{2mm} % Minor grid size
    \def\majorsize{1cm} % Major grid size
    
    % Calculate the adjusted positions for the grid
    \path (current page.south west) ++(20mm,23mm) coordinate (grid sw); % bottom left point
    \path (current page.north east) ++(-20mm,-23.8mm) coordinate (grid ne); % top right point
    
    % Draw the minor grid
    \draw[black!20, step=\minorsize] (grid sw) grid (grid ne);
    
    % Draw the major grid
    \draw[black!50, step=\majorsize] (grid sw) grid (grid ne);
\end{tikzpicture}\newpage

\vspace{10mm}\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \label{grid}
    % Define the size of the grid squares
    \def\minorsize{2mm} % Minor grid size
    \def\majorsize{1cm} % Major grid size
    
    % Calculate the adjusted positions for the grid
    \path (current page.south west) ++(20mm,25.8mm) coordinate (grid sw); % bottom left point
    \path (current page.north east) ++(-20mm,-41mm) coordinate (grid ne); % top right point
    
    % Draw the minor grid
    \draw[black!20, step=\minorsize] (grid sw) grid (grid ne);
    
    % Draw the major grid
    \draw[black!50, step=\majorsize] (grid sw) grid (grid ne);
\end{tikzpicture}\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \label{grid}
    % Define the size of the grid squares
    \def\minorsize{2mm} % Minor grid size
    \def\majorsize{1cm} % Major grid size
    
    % Calculate the adjusted positions for the grid
    \path (current page.south west) ++(20mm,123mm) coordinate (grid sw); % bottom left point
    \path (current page.north east) ++(-20mm,-23.8mm) coordinate (grid ne); % top right point
    
    % Draw the minor grid
    \draw[black!20, step=\minorsize] (grid sw) grid (grid ne);
    
    % Draw the major grid
    \draw[black!50, step=\majorsize] (grid sw) grid (grid ne);
\end{tikzpicture}\vspace{153mm}

\end{document}
```

(I don't expect the space or geometry settings to affect the problem I'm having, but have included in case this is what it is coming back to)

Comment: If you use `remember picture`, you typically need two compilation cycles because some information is written to the .aux file in the first compilation cycle and this information is then used in the second run.

Comment: Instead of directly compiling with xelatex, you could use latexmk, which will automatically compile the document the required number of times  `latexmk --xelatex document.tex`

Comment: Interesting stuff! Kinda interested in how TeXstudio did things only calling one process, but presumably it's just a case of hiding things from me. Thanks for the latexmk tip